# Issue with POST data from Firefox Mobile

Tags: html, firefox, post, mobile

I have an HTML5 app that POSTs data packets to the server, from where the the packets are combined and converted to sql statements for insertion into a MSSQL db. Each POST packet is 300000 bytes. This works perfectly well when I run the app from my desktop Firefox (Windows 7 machine), and I'm able to up the ante to even triple this size (I haven't encountered a limit yet). However, this doesn't seem to work at all when I test from my android phone's Firefox. I was able to get it to work at a paltry 10000 bytes but this time, no response. Since I can't get firebug to help me out here, I'm stuck. Is there a limit to POST packets on mobile browsers, or mobile Firefox generally?

EDIT: I realized my problem may not have to do with the size of the POST packet per se, as explained below. That said, I still haven't figured out what the issue is!

As requested below, this is the client side code I used to test:

```
var big_data = '';          
        for(i=0;i<80000;i++){
            big_data += 'abcdefgh';
        }

            var iframe_jquery = $("<iframe>").appendTo(document.body); 
            var iframe = iframe_jquery.get(0);            
            var uniqueString = "myiFrame";  
            iframe.style.display = "none";
            iframe.contentWindow.name = uniqueString;
            // construct a form with hidden inputs, targeting the iframe                
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.id = "form_offlinesync";
            form.target = uniqueString;
            form.action = server_url;
            form.method = "POST";

            // repeat for each parameter    
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.id = "postifydatify";
            input.type = "hidden";
            input.name = "postifydatify";
            input.value = big_data;
            form.appendChild(input);    
document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();
```

And this is the server side bit that received the request:

```
Log(context.Request.Form["postifydatify"].ToString());
Log(context.Request.Form["postifydatify"].ToString().Length + " is length of POST data");
```

Comment: I don't know about POST size limits on FF mobile, but you identified the problem. When you send POST data and get no answer, it is because the POST data is too big. Usually, you can configure the maximum size of the POST data in the server configuration files. Hope it helps solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Heru-Luin. I think the server side isn't an issue since I can send the data perfectly well to the same server from my desktop.... if there was someway to get firebug or its equivalent running on the mobile!

Comment: Well, I haven't yet solved my problem yet, but I think my assumption was wrong, i.e, the POST packet size might not be the issue. I created a small page to simply POST a packet, tested from my phone and it has sent a packet of 640000 bytes (haven't come across a limit) so my problem lies elsewhere, I suppose.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the client side and server side code ?